# Can you run an ant build script as part of a Hudson deployment?

Tags: ant, hudson, build-automation

We want to be able to deploy our project using Hudson, but the build file for the project generates some files and downloads packages from other locations.

Is it possible to make Hudson do these tasks as part of a deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hudson (Jenkins) has support for [Ant](http://ant.apache.org), so yes, you can run any deployment tasks specified in your Ant scripts.

Answer (score 0):

And here is the link to the corresponding page in the hudson wiki: [Building A Software Project](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-AntScripts)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven ant plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to run ant script in hudson without configuring hudson. This is good for running the ant script manuelly as well as using hudson.